# NoForeignKeysError on One to Many Relationship - SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm writing the backend of a simple e-commerce site with Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy but i'm having trouble with SQLAlchemy db creation.

The DB diagram is as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCNzr.png)

I wrote the models for my database but when i try to test them i'm getting this error message on the One to Many relationship between **Parent** and **OrderItem**:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Product.order_item - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

The models are the following:

```py
class OrderItem(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'OrderItem'
    order_item_number = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    order_quantity = db.Column(db.Integer())
    order_item_product_number = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('Product.product_number'))
    order_item_order_number = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('Order.order_number'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<OrderItem {}{}>'.format(self.order_item_number, self.order_order_item)


class Product(db.Model):

    _tablename__ = 'Product'

    product_number = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    product_availability = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    product_price = db.Column(db.Integer())
    product_unit = db.Column(db.Integer())
    product_discount = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=0)
    order_item = db.relationship('OrderItem', backref='Product')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Product {}'.format(self.product_number)
```

Everything seems correct, i have the very same relationship pattern with Customer and Order but i don't get why i'm getting prompted with this error here.
I've already checked for any mistyping in attribute names but everything seems correct, from the table names to the attribute names.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `_tablename__ = 'Product'` appears to be missing a leading underscore meaning that Flask-SQLAlchemy is probably setting the name of that table to `'product'` with a lower case 'p' which in turn means `db.ForeignKey('Product.product_number')` isn’t actually ref’ing your product table.. I haven’t tested but seems plausible.

Comment: sqlite schema is not case sensitive.  Perhaps the case matters to SQLAlchemy, but not the database.

Comment: Missing a `>` bracket in `return '<Product {}'.format(self.product_number)`?

Comment: Seems @SuperShoot was right, i changed every tablename to lower case pep8 and the problems seems gone.  Now i'm getting a 
`sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.module' is not mapped `
but that should be due to the fact that i'm importing the wrong db instance in the model definition.

Comment: Glad that something worked, but did you event get the point of SuperShoot's comment?  He didn't recommend changing the case, rather he recommended adding an underscore to `_tablename__` to make it consistent.  He only mentioned the case of the table as a side effect of the typo.  You should still fix the two typos that we pointed out.

Comment: Oh god, i completely misunderstood that! I was so focused on understanding table name conversion before posting this question that i entered in "tunnel-vision" mode and only looked for that. Thanks for pointing out!